# How to delete data from firebase via functions?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to delete old notifications from firestore via functions.
I don't know how to go threw all documents and its subcollections in a collection.

The db tree looks like this:[image]

EDIT:

This is what I tryed:

```
    const functions = require('firebase-functions');
    const admin = require('firebase-admin');
    admin.initializeApp();
exports.deleteoldnotifications = functions.https.onRequest((req: any, res: { status: (arg0: number) => { send: () => void; }; }) => {
    const timeNow = new Date();
    const db = admin.firestore();
    db.collection('notification').get().then((snap: { forEach: (arg0: (collection: any) => void) => void; }) => {
        snap.forEach((collection: any) => {
            db.collection('notification').doc(collection.id).collection('messages').get().then((snapshot: { forEach: (arg0: (doccollection: any) => void) => void; }) => {
                snapshot.forEach((doccollection) => {
                    const durations = new Date(doccollection.data().duration);
                    if (durations <= timeNow) {
                        doccollection.delete();
                        console.log('duration: ',doccollection.duration);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    });
    return null;
});
```

The function is finished with timeout.

How to go threw the noticifation collection and delete the old ones?

Comment: What is this `(snap: { forEach: (arg0: (collection: any) => void) => void; })` supposed to accomplish?

Comment: Your updated code doesn't write any response, which eventually causes it to time out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as `functions.firestore`, which is precisely what the error message says.

If you want to access Firestore in a function that is not triggered from Firestore itself, you use the Admin SDK to do so. You're already importing the Admin SDK in your code, so all that is needed is:

```
admin.firestore().doc(...)
```

Comment: Now its giving me this TypeError: admin.firestore(...).document is not a function

Comment: Ok,so it was admin.firestore().doc(...) instead of admin.firestore().document(...),but how am I able to go threw all the documents?

Comment: Your original code tried to load a single document, so that's what my answer does too. To load multiple documents, read the documentation on [getting all documents in a collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_collection).

Comment: I have edited the question,can you answer it now? I debugged it,it says the duration is undefined, I guess I'm calling it wrong..

Comment: Keep in mind that I already answered your original problem, which was caused by accessing the Admin SDK with an invalid syntax. Now you've changed the question, so that my answer no longer matches, making it useless for any developers who may land here in the future.